# The foreign key component 'X' is not a declared property on type 'Y'. Verify that it has not been explicitly excluded

Tags: c#, entity-framework

It seems this is a pretty common issue, but I've tried everything and can't see any issues.

It seems as if this issue just started today. Full error message:

"The foreign key component 'AllocationID' is not a declared property on type 'PortfolioSection'. Verify that it has not been explicitly excluded from the model and that it is a valid primitive property."

Model:

```
public class PortfolioSection 
{
    .... some stuff

    public int AllocationID { set; get; }

    [ForeignKey("AllocationID")]
    public virtual Allocation Allocation { get; set; }

    .... More stuff

}
public class Allocation 
{

    ... Some stuff



    [ForeignKey("PortfolioSections")]
    public int AllocationID { set; get; }


    public string Name { set; get;}


    public string Color { set; get; }


    public int SortOrder { set; get; }




    public virtual List<PortfolioSection> PortfolioSections { get; set; }


}
```

I'm not doing anything weird w/ the configuration that I can see that would cause this issue. Could it be that the key for Allocation is AllocationID and not just ID?

So far I've tried:
1. Removing the navigation property from PorfolioSection to Allocation.
2. Putting the ForiegnKey attribute on AllocationID (ForeignKey("Allocation")) instead of the navigation property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a few attributes that are misplaced. If you change:

```
[ForeignKey("PortfolioSections")]
public int AllocationID { set; get; }
```

To:

```
[Key]
public int AllocationID { set; get; }
```

Then this should work fine. The issue is that you declared the Key (AllocationID is the primary key I am assuming) as a ForeignKey to the PortfolioSections table.

Comment: Thanks, that worked. I don't know why it suddenly started to fail - this code is in production and working fine!